# Javascript calculate sum unless it is less than zero

Tags: javascript, formula

Just a quick question, can this sum be written in one short line:

```
  a = (b / c) * 100;
  if (a < 0) a = 0;
```

Apart from the obvious way which is equally long:

```
 if ((b / c) * 100) > 0) a = (b / c) * 100; else a = 0;
```

EDIT: And the ternary version of this is no different, I didn't think I needed to mention.

Maybe there isn't a short, neat and clever way to write this but I was just hoping there was since it always seems unnecessary to have that extra line underneath.

Comment: Where's the sum? :-?

Comment: In the question..

Comment: English is a foreign language for me. Does "sum" mean something else apart from addition?

Comment: I think he asked where the sum is because the definition of a sum is the total found by *adding* numbers, and since there’s no plus signs anywhere, there is no sum in this question. Still, we knew what you meant.

Comment: @Álvaro González yes sum can refer to an arithmetical problem. It's not incorrect in English at all.

Comment: _Cociente_ is _quotient_ and  _producto_ is _product_, but in this case I'd just call it _result_.

Comment: @Nate Sum has several meanings. It can also mean an amount, as in 'a sum of money'.

Comment: I've definitively learnt something today. Thank you.

Comment: Oooohhh. I got all hung up on math class... “sum”, “product”, etc

Comment: @Nate It is generally used to mean addition, it's true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could take `Math.max` along with zero.

```
a = Math.max(b * 100 / c, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary operator:

```
a = ((b / c) * 100) >= 0 ? ((b / c) * 100) : 0;
```

Comment: That's what I was trying to avoid. See the second part of my question.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a ternary expression:

```
a = (b / c) * 100 > 0 ? (b / c) * 100 : 0;
```

This assigns `a` to the quantity `(b / c) * 100`, unless that quantity be less than or equal to zero, in which case it just assigns zero to `a`.

Comment: That's what I was trying to avoid. See the second part of my question.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your current code, and I would probably leave it as is.  My answer offers one possibility to do it in a one liner.

Comment: Yes but I did specifically say "apart from the obvious' way. I already wrote that method in my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
// I do not think that *100 is necessary in your test
a = (b / c) < 0 ? 0 : (b / c) * 100;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way I can think of

```
a = (b / c * 100) >= 0 ? (b / c * 100) : 0;
```

Comment: Doing the calculation twice is inefficient.

Comment: @Nate Yeah you're right, that's exactly what I was trying to avoid, so I described it in my question but still most of the answers seem to use this double calculation method.

Comment: Yeah, the people of StackOverflow don’t often think about performance.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the result is negative if one of b or c is negative (but not both). So a bit longer but actually with only necessary calculations and more comparisons:

```
b < 0 ? c > 0 ? a = 0 : a = b * 100  / c : c < 0 ? a = b * 100 : a = 0;
```